# Caching Problem in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a list of objects in an asp.net page. Each object represents a product of a shop, consisting of the name of the product, product id, price, available quantity etc. A customer can select a product from a drop down list, and the corresponding fields, such as price, quantity etc are automatically filled with the appropriate values. For performance reason, when the page loads I have fetched the whole list of products from the database and stored it inside the "Cache['Product']" variable, so that when the value change event of the drop down occurs, I can get the corresponding values without any database queries.

This strategy works fine in my local development environment, but when the page is uploaded to the server, the corresponding fields are not getting appropriate values. Even when a product is selected from the drop down, the corresponding fields are not showing the appropriate price, quantity etc. Seems like my caching strategy is not working.

I don't know what is wrong here. I have set the cache variable as follows :

```
if(Cache["ProductList"] == null)
            Cache.Insert("ProductList", Product, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

When I need to retrieve the cache values, I have done it like below :

```
List<Product> CachedProduct = (List<Product> )Cache["ProductList"];
```

I have absolutely no idea what could be the problem here. I need some help :(

Comment: Just one server or several ones? Are your "ProductList" procedure retrieving correct data? Are your data correct?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "is not working"?  Nothing shows up?  The wrong items show up?  The secondary drop downs aren't seeing the right values?  What's *not* happening matters :)

Comment: By "is not working" I meant that when a user selects a different product from the drop down list, that means, when the drop down's "selectedIndexChanged" event occurs, the values in the quantity field, price fields should change according to the new product. Now sometimes it changes, sometimes it doesn't. But at my localhost, it does not causes any problem.

Comment: @Rubens: Yes, my product list procedure is retrieving correct data, and they are all available in the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you experience different behavior locally than on a server, this may have something to do with the configuration of the server. If you have access to that, check whether there are some differences. Otherwise you might want to post a more detailed sample of your code ;)